# Entering checkbox values correctly in database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I have a simplified the following example to illustrate my question.

I would like to opinions from logged-in users using checkboxes.
For instance, a dynamic list would be displayed listing various fruits, with two checkboxes next to each kind of fruit, meaning "Yes, I like this" and "No, I don't like this". A user could check either checkbox, or don't check one of the checkboxes at all.
It would look somewhat like this:

> [] [] Apple
>
> [] [] Pear
>
> [] [] Orange
>
> [ Submit ]

It then needs to be submitted to a MySQL database, with the following structure.
It may not be the easiest setup, but unfortunately this is all I can work with at the moment. (opinion being a numeric value, representing "yes" or "no")

> ID | UserID | Fruit | Opinion

How would I go about making this?

Comment: Your question is too broad, what is the question? How to set up the form and dynamically load the options, or how to save them to your database? Please enlighten me. :)

Comment: Sorry! My question is how to store the results in the database using INSERT INTO. How do I make the difference between YES or NO when posting an array to MySQL.

Comment: You check which option (based on the value you give it) is selected and insert the yes or no (or 0 / 1 ) to the db.

Comment: What is the best way to do this? I've tried IF/ELSE but this filters the whole list at once, not making any difference when e.g. one option is the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Let's say the field `Opinion` is a tinyint, where 0=NO and 1=YES.

You say you dynamically load your 'fruits', I don't know if it's an array or if the data comes out of a database. You might need to alter the code to that, I just presume it's an array. We will create a form with all the fruits and the option yes and no

```
<?php
$fruits = array( 'apple', 'pear', 'orange' );

echo '<form ...>';
foreach( $fruits as $fruit ) {
   echo '<p>Do you like ' . $fruit . '</p>';
   echo '<input type="radio" name="fruits[' . $fruit . ']" value="0" /> No ';
   echo '<input type="radio" name="fruits[' . $fruit . ']" value="1" /> Yes ';
}
echo '</form>';
?>
```

You'll need to add some more code to make it functional.

Next, we'll need to process the form.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
   foreach( $_POST['fruits'] as $fruit => $opinion) {
      $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tableName (UserID, Fruit, Opinion) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
      $stmt->bind_param('isi', $userID, $fruit, $opinion);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->close();
   }
}
?>
```

I presume you know how to call the data back from the database to display it. With the opinion you can simply use something like:

```
<?php
$opinion = ( $row['opinion'] == 1 ) 'yes' : 'no';
echo 'User: ' . $row['UserID'] . '<br />';
echo 'Fruit: ' . $row['fruit'] . '<br />';
echo 'Opinion: ' . $opinion . '<br />';
?>
```

The above chunks of code aren't complete, but it will help you on your way. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! This seems like a great start for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use TINYINT datatype in mysql to store boolean values like yes or no. Use value 0 for 'NO' and value 1 for 'YES'.